# Error selecting rows where decimal > 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I keep getting the error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

When executing this query:

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.EMPL_RCD, A.DZ_PRESENCE_TYPE, A.DZ_DATE, A.DZ_TIME_HOURS
FROM PS_DZ_TIME_VW A 
WHERE A.DZ_PRESENCE_TYPE IN ('P50', 'FORF') AND A.DZ_TIME_HOURS > 0
```

`A.DZ_TIME_HOURS` is a decimal value, when I execute the query without the `'AND A.DZ_TIME_HOURS > 0'` the query runs fine and returns values like `0.00000` or `3.11400`.
The goal is to only display values above 0.

Edit: I forgot to add  `EXEC sp_help PS_DZ_TIME_VW` tells me `A.DZ_TIME_HOURS` is a decimal type with length 5, Prec 7 and scale 5.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure that `A.DZ_TIME_HOURS` is decimal? I mean, you - human being - read it as a decimal of course, but how is stored inside db table? To me, and to dbms too, seems to be declared as a varchar not a decimal

Comment: This is very strange ...

Comment: What happens if you execute the following query: `SELECT * FROM PS_DZ_TIME_VW WHERE DZ_TIME_HOURS > 0.0` ?

Comment: It just occured to me that PS_DZ_TIME_VW could be a view. The error could therefore potentially be comming from the SQL-query making up the view.

Comment: @Dan yes that's right, the `DZ_TIME_HOURS` gets filled by this statement: `CAST((SUBSTRING(HOURSSTRING,1,3)+'.'+SUBSTRING(HOURSSTRING,4,5)) AS DECIMAL(7,5)) HOURS`

Comment: There's your answer. You need to make sure that HOURSSTRING always conforms to the first 3 characters being integers, and the 5 characters after 4th letter also being integers. This seems not to be the case, since you're getting an error. Are you trying to change a decimal character from comma to period? In that case, why not simply use `CAST(REPLACE(HOURSSTRING,',','.') AS DECIMAL(7,5))`

Comment: @Dan I just tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us what the contents of the HOURSSTRING looks like? Maybe the string has other characters than commas and integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague came up with a solution/workaround:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, DZ_PRESENCE_TYPE, DZ_DATE, SUM(DZ_TIME_HOURS) HOURS
FROM PS_DZ_TIME_VW 
GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, DZ_PRESENCE_TYPE, DZ_DATE
) A
WHERE A.HOURS > 0
```

He thinks this has something to do with how the database handles the query. 
In our Oracle db the query ran without problems.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the casting? (you may need to specify length precision\scale etc) :

```
CAST(A.DZ_TIME_HOURS AS DECIMAL) > 0
```

Just noticed your collation. Seems unfamiliar to me. This could have an affect as different datatypes are treated differently depending on local. But DECIMAL\VARCHAR issues seems weird...

Comment: It's a view built from Oracle Peoplesoft. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Since your column is of type decimal this error should not happen but still explicitly convert the column to decimal and try. Not very sure if this will help though. Also try to check with `0.0` instead of `0`

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.EMPL_RCD, A.DZ_PRESENCE_TYPE, A.DZ_DATE, A.DZ_TIME_HOURS
FROM PS_DZ_TIME_VW A 
WHERE A.DZ_PRESENCE_TYPE IN ('P50', 'FORF') AND CAST(CAST(A.DZ_TIME_HOURS AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(7,5)) > 0.0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: your query throws error: The scale must be less than or equal to the precision.

Comment: Change DECIMAL(5,7) to DECIMAL(7,5)

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. Updated my post. :)

Comment: Then I get the error converting data type varchar to numeric again.